# find_package Config file with components

Tags: cmake

i have a cmake package with a Config file supporting components, e.g.

```
find_package(myPack REQUIRED COMPONENTS foo bar)
```

in myPackConfig.cmake I typically do

```
foreach(comp ${myPack_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    if(TARGET myPack::${comp})
         find_package(${comp})
    endif()
endif()
```

i.e. loop all components and find them. But is it possible to include ALL components if none is given? E.g. when doing

```
find_package(myPack)
```

I want to have ALL components (foo, bar, baz et.c.)

thanks

Comment: Is you problem to **check** whether no *COMPONENTS* are given to `find_package()` call or to **find all targets** matches `myPack::*`?

Comment: To find all valid targets that matches what you say

Comment: Just realized, one way would be to add a MyPack library without namespace and then glob all componentConfig.cmake files , that might work ... perhsps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you need to iterate over list of all targets, and find ones which matches given pattern (`myPack::*`).

CMake has property [BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html)... but it lists only non-*IMPORTED* targets, so it doesn't fit.

Common CMake pattern to obtain the list of created "objects" is to **intercept** commands created such object and force them to add objects into the list. This approach works for collecting targets list:

**myPackConfig.cmake**:

```
# ... Somewhere at the beginnning, before including other files.
set(targets_list) # It will be maintained as a list of targets created
# Replace `add_library()` call
function (add_library name)
    # Add library target name to the list
    list(APPEND targets_list ${name})
    # And perform original actions
   _add_library (${name} ${ARGN})
endfunction (add_library)

# Include `*.cmake` files created by CMake.
...

# After all 'include()'s iterate over targets list and collect needed ones.
set(all_component_targets)
foreach(t ${targets_list})
    if(t MATCHES "myPack::.*")
        list(APPEND all_component_targets ${t})
    endif()
endforeach()

# Now 'all_component_targets' contains all targets prefixed with "myPack::".
```

(That approach has been suggested in CMake [mailing list](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039388.html)).

Comment: That works, but sortof hacky though. Strange its not more supported

Comment: Actually, what you want(generating list of components *automatically*) is some sort of "hack". The more natural way would be creating complete list of components manually: CMake know nothing about meaning of the "component" for your case. But list of all targets seems something what CMake could provide. Not sure why *BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS* is restricted about *IMPORTED* targets.